# .bashrc variable for ./command

Tags: linux, command, executable, bash

In linux, for a command that I have to run like `./command` ; how do I set a `.bashrc` environment variable to run the `command` from any directory without having to put the full path for the command.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add the directory to the path.

Tutorial: [Adding a Directory to the Path](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You modify the PATH environmental variable like so

```
PATH=${PATH}:/the/directory/to/the/executable
export PATH
```

Note that you cannot actually include the executable, which means it's full path would look like

```
/the/directory/to/the/executable/command
```

For executables that override common utilities, to make the executable be found first, you need to reverse the order, like so

```
PATH=/the/directory/to/the/executable:${PATH}
export PATH
```

Comment: I did add the path. But the executable is to be run like `./command`. There is other executable that I have to run, which works fine without the `./` by adding the path as you have said

Comment: It the above doesn't work, perhaps you have the wrong question.  Does the command launch but crash with `command`?  If so, then perhaps the executable is mis-written to not handle being launched from a different working directory.  In such a case, you might want to alias `command` with `cd directory; command`

Comment: say my path it `/home/user/tool`. There are two executables in this path; say `command1` and `command2`. The way I have to run these executables is `./command1` and `command2`. So if I set the path as you said; I can run `command2` from anywhere by just typing `command2` but not `./command1`. I want to be able to run `./command1` by just typing `command1` from any directory.

Comment: After you made your changes, did you re-read your `.bashrc`?  Typically it is read on login, but you can force your environment to re-read it by typeing `. .bashrc`.  Note the `.`, which is the "source this shell script" command, and make sure you are in the home directory (or change the .bashrc file to include a full path).

Comment: Changes are still there even when I login again. `. .bashrc` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't posting the information needed to solve your issue?  Talking about entries you haven't shown tends to make problem solving even more difficult than it is with such information at hand.  Edit your question to include the relevant sections of `.bashrc` and the output from `echo ${SHELL}`.  Odds are good you have a typo somewhere (or have missed a critical step in the above directions).